# Отправка почты c#

Tags: c#, smtp

```
EmailSend.SendMailRu(item.Email, tema, body, item.FromEmail, item.SmtpClient, item.SmtpPort, item.LoginEmail, item.PasswordEmail, file);
```

выше код по вызову метода отправки, ниже сам метод отправки - через прокси не работает, а с компьютера где нет прокси, отправляет только на яндекс, остальные почтовые клиенты не получают сообщения.

```
public static void SendMailRu(string toEmail, string subject, string body, string from, string smtp_client, int smtp_port, string login, string password,string file)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp_client, smtp_port);

    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.To.Add(toEmail);
    message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.From = new MailAddress(from);

    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = HEADER+body+ FOOTER;

    if (smtp_port!=25)
    {
        client.EnableSsl = true;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
    {
        Attachment sendFile = new Attachment(file);
        message.Attachments.Add(sendFile);
    }

    client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Папку спам проверяли? Скорее всего туда письма попали.

Comment: Проверял - пусто в спаме

Comment: через какой сервер отправляете?

Answer (score 2):

настройте в DNS подпись DKIM, должно заработать. Только подождать придеться, пока DNS обновятся

немного о DKIM тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/106589/