# Отправить сообщение на e-mail

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть необходимость автоматической рассылки писем на почту. Как отправить письмо с прикрепленным скриншотом на определенный e-mail?

---

Суть такая, что при возникновении ошибки пользователь может на жать на кнопку "Отправить" и скрин ошибки автоматически отправится администратору по e-mail.

Comment: Можно, для этого вам понадобится `SMTP` или `POP3` сервер. Посмотрите [этот](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/3991/smtp-and-pop3-mail-server) проект, чтобы разобраться что к чему.

Comment: Похожих вопросов не мало, например http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457072/ , может уточните, что именно нужно?

Comment: Суть такая, что при возникновении ошибки пользователь может на жать на кнопку "Отправить" и скрин ошибки автоматически отправится администратору по e-mail.

Comment: Message.Attachments.Add(attach);

Comment: да даже в том вопросе с атачментом было

Comment: @АлександрПузанов я закрыл вопрос, т.к. совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите видеть в ответе. Вы явно написали что вам нужно снять скрин и приаттачить его к письму. При этом отметили как принятый ответ, в котором нет ничего о снятии скрина. И ничего об аттаче файла. Не стоит отмечать как принятые те ответы, которые не соответствуют вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   //в главе файла нужно добавит using System.Net.Mail;
 // настройка логина, пароля отправителя

string from = "somemail@yandex.com";
            string pass = "password";
        string to = "destinition@gmail.com";

        // адрес и порт smtp-сервера, с которого мы и будем отправлять письмо
        // для других сервисов адрес и порт можно найти по гуглив
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);

        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        // создаем письмо: to - адрес получателя
        var mail = new MailMessage(from,to);

        mail.Subject = "Message Subject";
        mail.Body = "Message Mody";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Для отправкии вызиваем метод Send обекта client
        client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: человеку картинку ещё надо вставить в атачмент, комменты почитайте к посту

Answer (score 2):

Две функции для полной реализации отправки скрина на email, возможно кому-то понадобится:

```
void PostScreen()
{
    Graphics graph = null;
    var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memStream.Position = 0;
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
        contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
        contentType.Name = "screen.jpg";
        Attachment att = new Attachment(memStream, contentType);
        post(att);
    }
}
void post(Attachment a)
{
    string from = "somemail@yandex.com";
    string pass = "password";
    string to = "destinition@gmail.com";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    var mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
    mail.Subject = "Тема";
    mail.Body = "Письмо письмо письмо";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Attachments.Add(a);
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

по вопросу в комментах, чтобы взять только окно формы, чуток переделываем функцию postScreen()

```
void PostScreen()
{
    Graphics graph = null;
    var bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    graph.CopyFromScreen(this.Top, this.Left, 0, 0, this.Size);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        memStream.Position = 0;
        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
        contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
        contentType.Name = "screen.jpg";
        Attachment att = new Attachment(memStream, contentType);
        post(att);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если нужен скрин не всего экрана, а текущего окна (Alt+PrtScr)?

Comment: можно попробовать обрезать bitmap на величину соответствующей top-left до top+height, left+width окна, прежде чем отправлять.

Comment: добавил в ответ

Answer (score -1):

Когда-то написал кривоватый но рабочий код для рассылки писем с аттачем.

(Функция "Proc()" генерировала аттачмент, сохраняла его и возвращала путь к файлу.)

```
//шлём почтой fileName

string smtpHost = "mail.blabla.ru";    //smtp сервер    
int smtpPort = 25;                     //smtp порт    
string login = "login@blabla.ru";   //логин                
string pass = "pass";    //пароль

//создаем подключение

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, pass);

//От кого письмо           
string from = "login@blabla.ru";
//Кому письмо
string to = "client@blabla.ru";
string subject = "Тема письма";
string body = "Текст письма";                
//Вложение для письма
//Если нужно не одно вложение, для каждого создаем отдельный Attachment
Attachment attData = new Attachment(Proc());                
//Создаем сообщение
MailMessage mess = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
//прикрепляем вложение
mess.Attachments.Add(attData);
try
{
     client.Send(mess);
}
catch (SmtpException)
{
     throw new Exception("Ошибка отправки письма.");  
}
```